# Is the set of positive-definite symmetric matrices open in the set of all matrices?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

So if $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ is the set of square real matrix of order $n$ then it is well know that the position
$$
\langle A,B\rangle:=\text{tr}(AB^T)
$$
defines an inner product on $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ so that this set is a topological vector space.

Now I'd like to prove that the subset
$$
\text{Sym}_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R):=\big\{A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R):A=A^T\wedge \vec v\cdot A\vec v>0\,\,\text{for any }\vec v\in\Bbb R^{n}\setminus\{0\}\big\}
$$
is open. So first of all I observed that if $\text{Sym}_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ and $M^+_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ and are the sets of symmetric matrices and the set of positive definite matrices, that is
$$
\text{Sym}_{n\times n}(\Bbb R):=\big\{A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R):A=A^T\big\}\\
M^+_{n\times n}(\Bbb R):=\big\{A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R):\vec v\cdot A\vec v>0\,\,\text{for any }\vec v\in \Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}\big\}
$$
then
$$
\text{Sym}_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)=\text{Sym}_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)\cap M_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)
$$
so that the result would follow immediately showing that $M_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)$ is an open set disjoint form the boundary of $\text{Sym}_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ because this last is a linear subspace and any linear subspace of a finite dimensional t.v.s is closed so that in this case the above intersection is exactly equal to the intersection
$$
\operatorname{int}\Big(\text{Sym}_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)\Big)\cap M_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)
$$

Now let be $\varphi:M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)\rightarrow\Bbb R^{n\cdot n}$ the function defined through the equation
$$
\varphi(X):=(X_1,\dots ,X_n)=\big((x_{1,1},\dots,x_{1,n}),\dots,(x_{n,1},\dots,x_{n,n})\big)
$$
for any $X\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ and thus we observe that it is an isomorphism (moreover it is not hard to show that it is an isometry) and thus a homeomorphism becuase any ismorphism between finite dimensional t.v.s is an homeomorphism. So the statement can be proved showing that $\varphi\Big[M_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)\Big]$ is open and disjoint form the boundary of $\varphi\Big[\text{Sym}_{3\times 3}(\Bbb R)\Big]$ but unfortunately I was not able to prove this; alternatively the statement can be proved aslo showing that $\varphi\Big[\text{Sym}_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)\Big]$ but I yet was not be able to do this.

Finally I have to point out that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743056/set-of-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-open) I found a question where is exatly ask to prove what I ask now but unfortunately it seems it is only proved that the set of positive matrices is open: indeed no answers there was accepted. Anyway I would not mind now that even here it proves that the set of positive matrices is open: indeed in the [Ovi's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3808498) there is something is not clear.

So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix, and let
$$
\delta = \inf x\cdot Ax > 0,
$$
where the infimum is taken over all *unit* vectors $x$.

Now let
$A+B$ be a symmetric perturbation of $A$. Then for any *unit* vector $x$, we have
$$
x\cdot(A+B)x = x \cdot Ax + x \cdot Bx,
$$
and
$$
|x \cdot Bx|\leq\|B\|\|x\|^2 = \|B\|,
$$
so that
$$
x \cdot(A+B)x \geq \delta - \|B\|.
$$
This shows that if $B$ is small enough then $A+B$ is positive definite.

Note that the set of *symmetric* positive definite matrices is *not* open in the space of *all* matrices (because a general perturbation destroys symmetricity), but open within the subspace of *symmetric* matrices, with respect to the subspace topology.

Note also that this argument works verbatim for the general positive definite case with general perturbations.

Comment: So if $E$ is a unit matrix (that is $\|E\|=1)$ then the you proved that for any $\lambda<\delta$ 
the inequality
$$
x\cdot(A+\lambda E)x\ge\delta-\|\lambda E\|=\delta-\lambda>0
$$
holds and this proves that if $A$ is an element of $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ then the ball $\mathcal B(A,r)$ of radius $r<\delta$ centered at $A$ is contained in $M_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)$ so that we can conclude that this last set is open, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yes that’s correct

Comment: Okay, fine. Anyway I do not understand what you mean by the term symmetric perturbation: could you explain? pheraps you want means that $B$ is symmetric?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yes that means B is symmetric

Comment: Okay, so finally your proved that for any $A\in\text{Sym}_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)$ there exist $r>0$ such that $$\mathcal B(A,r)\cap\text{Sym}_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)\subseteq\text{Sym}_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)$$ and **this inclusion** exactly proves that the set $\text{Sym}_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)$ is open $\text{Sym}_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro right

Comment: Okay, very fine: question upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance!!!

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot: so unfortunatley the set $\varphi\Big[\text{Sym}_{n\times n}^+(\Bbb R)\Big]$ is not open in $\Bbb R^{n\cdot n}$ but only in $\varphi\Big[\text{Sym}_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)\Big]$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yes that’s right.

Comment: Okay, thanks yet. See you soon.